# i2c bus not seen on debian

Tags: debian, i2c

I have a single board computer with debian jessie installed on it.

On this board, there is 2 RTC. One that is not backed up that correspond to rtc-cmos and the other one that is backed up and is accessible by i2c bus.

With a i2cdetect -l I obtain only :

```
i2c-0   smbus           SMBus I801 adapter at 4000              SMBus adapter
```

I thought that normally i will have another line with i2c-1 etc...
How can i know that the i2c bus is activated ?
Do I need to load a specific kernel module or do I need a driver ?

Thanks in advance for any hints

Comment: Currently, only the SMBus of the Intel chipset is being detected. The I2C/SMBus is a very simple bus technology with very limited autodetection capabilities. Without knowing the specific hardware details of the board you have, it will be difficult to guess what might be needed to access your second RTC. There might be a I2C bus multiplexer somewhere on the first bus, or there might be an entire other I2C/SMBus adapter. If you know what the bus topology should be, you could try loading the appropriate modules manually.

Comment: Thanks for take time replying.

Comment: Thanks for take time replying. When i have a look at the datasheet of the board i am a little confused honnestly. To give some more details, I think there is an entire other i2c/smbus adapter. It appears like that on the diagram. It seems that the 6300esb ICH driver managed his RTC. And on the figure it exists another RTC from ST microelectronics (M41T62 driver). I already compiled the M41T62 driver as a module. This part is ok but even with the driver i only see the i2c-0. -naeco